# make horizontal stack view children center in iOS

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view which has two children. one is a label the other is an image  with fixed size. 
in most situations the sum of their widths is less than stack view width.

What I want is: (- is the space)

```
-----Label-Image-----
```

I tries UIStackView alignment **center**  and distribution **Equal spacing** or **equal centering**

Both results were:

```
Label------------Image
```

I can add  them in a UIView and do this, but I want stack view handle it if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create **UILable** and add it into one **StackView**.(set alignment **center** or **trailing**)(and text alignment has to be centre or right)

2.Create **UIImageview**(set **width** and **height**) and add it into one **stackview**.((set alignment **leading**)

3.Then add both **stackview** into another (horizontal) **stackview** and set alignment **center** and give **space** value as per your choice